# SQL - Join 3 entity tables and 2 relationship tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, relational-database

I am trying to write a SQL Join for 3 entity tables and 2 relationship tables.

The entity tables are:

- TJobs
- TCustomers
- TMaterials

The relationship tables are:

- TJobStatuses
- TJobMaterials

This query is returning correct results but they are duplicated 4 times:

```
SELECT
 TJS.intJobStatusID
,TJS.strStatus
,TJ.intJobID
,TC.strLastName + ', ' TC.strFirstName AS strCustomerName
,TC.intCustomerID
,TJ.dtmStartDate
,TJM.intMaterialQuantityID
,TM.intMaterialID
,TM.monCost
FROM
 TJobStatuses             AS TJS
,TJobs                    AS TJ
,TCustomers               AS TC
,TMaterials               AS TM
,TJobMaterials            AS TJM
WHERE
    TJS.intJobStatusID    = 3
AND TJ.intCustomerID      = TC.intCustomerID
AND TJ.intCustomerID      = 2
AND TM.intMaterialID      = TJM.intMaterialID
ORDER BY
 TJ.intJobID
,TM.intMaterialID
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I would say that you should switch to INNER JOIN syntax, this old JOIN is outdated 20 years ago. With INNER JOIN it will be more obvious to you what are you doing wrong. On the first sight TJS is fishy.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am taking a class taught by a very outdated professor who has only taught this syntax. How would I switch to INNER JOIN?

Comment: Check this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To use an inner join you need to select an id to link each table into a chain of sorts.

```
 SELECT
  TJS.intJobStatusID
  ,TJS.strStatus
  ,TJ.intJobID
  ,TC.strLastName + ', ' TC.strFirstName AS strCustomerName
  ,TC.intCustomerID
  ,TJ.dtmStartDate
  ,TJM.intMaterialQuantityID
  ,TM.intMaterialID
  ,TM.monCost
 FROM
  TJobStatuses             AS TJS
 JOIN
  TJobs                    AS TJ
 ON
    //TJS.someid = TJ.someid
JOIN
 TCustomers               AS TC
ON 
 TJ.intCustomerID      = TC.intCustomerID
JOIN
 TMaterials               AS TM
ON
     //someId = TM.someId
JOIN
 TJobMaterials            AS TJM
ON
 TM.intMaterialID      = TJM.intMaterialID,

 ORDER BY
  TJ.intJobID
 ,TM.intMaterialID
```